# Date in Reactive form is default printing as dd---yyyy in angular 2

Tags: angularjs

In .ts file

```
this.form = this.fb.group({
    .....
    ReceiptDateTime:['',],
)}
```

In .html file

```
<tr>
  <td width="50%"><label for ="ReceiptDateTime">Transaction date: </label></td>
 <td width="50%"><label> <input  type="date" formControlName="ReceiptDateTime" value ="receipt.ReceiptDateTime">  
</label></td>
</tr>
```

What occurs when we run is it is  reactive form defaultly print date text as dd---yyyy it does not take the value from the list .ReceiptDateTime contains date but is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Html portion:

```
<input type="date" formControlName="ReceiptDateTime" #myDate [value]="receipt.ReceiptDateTime| date:'yyyy-MM-dd'" (input)="receipt.CreatedDate=parseDate($event.target.value)" />
```

In ts portion declare parsedate function:

```
parseDate(dateString: string): Date {
    if (dateString) {
        return new Date(dateString);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
```